# Wordpress: issue on update_post_meta for checkbox metabox

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

I have a metabox (one checkbox) , in posts, to check if a post will be featured..

My code:

```
function add_featured_post_checkbox() {
  add_meta_box(
    'custom_featured_meta',
    'Featured post for Sidebar',
    'featured_post_checkbox_callback',
    'Post',
    'side',
    'high'
  );
} add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_featured_post_checkbox' );
```

Callback function:

```
function featured_post_checkbox_callback( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'custom_save_data' , 'custom_featured_nonce' );
    $featured = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_featured_post', true);
    echo "<label for='_featured_post'>".__('Is Featured? ', 'foobar')."</label>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='_featured_post' id='featured_post' value='1' " . checked(1, $featured) . " />";
  }
```

Save function:

```
function custom_save_data( $post_id ) {
 if( ! isset( $_POST['custom_featured_nonce'] ) ){
    return;
 }
 if( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['custom_featured_nonce'], 'custom_save_data') ) {
    return;
 }
 if( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){
    return;
 }
 if( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
    return;
 }
 if( ! isset( $_POST['_featured_post'] ) ) {
   return;
 }
 $my_data_featured = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_featured_post'] );
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured_post', $my_data_featured );
} add_action( 'save_post', 'custom_save_data' );
```

This code works well only when I want to make a post featured..

For example if a post is not checked as featured and I select the choice then database updated perfect (with value 1 in post_meta) and the ckeckbox has the tick on box

But after, If I try to uncheck and save the post then the ckeckbox is again with the tick and nothing changed in database..

I try to find a solution for days on stackoverflow and general in web but I can't find.

Please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a checkbox is unchecked, `$_POST` will not contain the key `_featured_post`.  Therefore, in your save callback, you need to change your strategy.  You do not want to bail out if the key is not set.  Rather, you either want to save a 0 or delete the post meta.  Let's go with the later option.

```
function custom_save_data( $post_id ) {
    if( ! isset( $_POST['custom_featured_nonce'] ) ){
        return;
    }

    if( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['custom_featured_nonce'], 'custom_save_data') ) {
        return;
    }
    if( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){
        return;
    }
    if( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['_featured_post'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured_post', 1 );
    } else {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured_post' );
    }
}
```

Notice that you do not need to use `sanitize_text_field()`. Why?  Because the value will only be a `1`.  That's it. Here we can hardcode that value.

### Another Problem I Saw

Running your code I saw that upon being checked, the HTML for `checked=checked` is being rendered as text.  Why? Because running the function [`checked()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked) will echo it out to the browser unless you tell it not to.  You'd have to check your code to:

```
checked(1, $featured, false);
```

Comment: Thank you for solution, and tip for the other problem : )

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because of return after the check if `_featured_post` is set in `$_POST` array. It's not set when you do not check the checkbox. Your approach here should be next

```
if (isset($_POST['_featured_post']))
{
    update_post_meta($object_id, '_featured_post', 1); // can only be 1 when checked anyway
}
else
{
    delete_post_meta($object_id, '_featured_post');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!